# Is there any way to hide/see JavaScript file pointed by <SRC> tag?

Tags: javascript

I have developed AES algorithm in JavaScript and Java for secure communication between browser and server. And I am using that JS file with  tag, now when we right click on the page we can see view source, in that view source only location of JavaScript file is visible. I am worried that whether any such tool is available that can retrieve that JavaScript file pointed by ? If yes then my key will be exposed. Is there any work around to it?

Comment: Java is to Javascript as car is to carpet.

Comment: If your JavaScript file is served by a simple `<script>` tag, then yes, everyone on the Internet can fetch it.

Comment: If the browser can see and use x.js then so can anyone/anything else. HTTPS/SSL/TLS are the way to provide security and prevent interception not home-brew solutions - particularly not ones employing symmetric cryptography.

Answer (score 2):

Your Javascript code executes on the **client**.
Therefore, the client can read and execute that code.

Client-side cryptography is (mostly) an exercise in futility.
Your system is not secure.

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that your javascript src tag looks like this:

```
 <script src="www.mydomain.com/scripts/login.js" />
```

Then all I need to do is put: www.mydomain.com/scripts/login.js in my address bar and I can read your JavaScript file plain as day. You might be interested in implementing some JavaScript obfuscation though.  Here is a decent post: [How can I obfuscate (protect) JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript) you can also Google 'JavaScript Obfuscation' for a multitude of information.

This is obviously security through obscurity which isn't really security at all but I suppose it is better then nothing in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the obfuscation suggestion. My src tag looks like
<script language="javascript1.2" type="text/javascript" src="/sbijava/js/sha512.js"></script>,
Still it can be accessible??

Comment: Yes.  Any file that your web page has access to your user implicitly has access to. The name of the JavaScript file does not matter. I would only need to type: www.yourdomain.com/sbijava/js/sha512.js in the browser and I can read the JS file plain as day.